# mysql ordering records based on different where

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Basically I want to get results in following order

1) First show all results where `users_packages`.`has_fair` = 1

2) Second show all results where

`users_packages`.`is_vip` = 1
AND 
`users_packages`.`has_fair` = 0

3) Third

`users_packages`.`has_fair` = 0
AND 
`users_packages`.`is_vip` = 0

Please guide me i need exactly all records in above orders that full fill each condition.THanks

Sql query is below

```
SELECT
    `users_packages`.*, `poster_websites`.*, `sub_cats`.`sub_cat_name_ar` AS `sub_cat_name_ar`,
    `sub_cats`.`sub_cat_name_en` AS `sub_cat_name_en`,
    `main_cats`.`cat_image_defult` AS `cat_image_defult`,
    `main_cats`.`slogen_cat_ar` AS `slogen_cat_ar`,
    `main_cats`.`slogen_cat_en` AS `slogen_cat_en`,
    `cities`.`city_name_ar` AS `city_name_ar`,
    `cities`.`city_name_en` AS `city_name_en`,
    `users`.`name` AS `use_name`,
    `users`.`user_postion` AS `user_postion`
FROM
    `poster_websites`
LEFT JOIN `main_cats` ON `main_cats`.`id` = `poster_websites`.`poster_cat_id`
LEFT JOIN `sub_cats` ON `sub_cats`.`id` = `poster_websites`.`poster_subcat_id`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `poster_websites`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `cities` ON `cities`.`id` = `poster_websites`.`city_id`

LEFT JOIN `users_packages` ON `users_packages`.`user_id` = `poster_websites`.`user_id`
WHERE
    `poster_websites`.`active` = 2
OR (
    `users_packages`.`has_fair` = 1
    AND `users_packages`.`expired_at` > '2020-06-09 11:54:26'
)
OR (
    `users_packages`.`is_vip` = 1
    AND `users_packages`.`has_fair` = 0
    AND `users_packages`.`expired_at` > '2020-06-09 11:54:26'
)
OR (
    `users_packages`.`has_fair` = 0
    AND `users_packages`.`is_vip` = 0
    AND `users_packages`.`expired_at` > '2020-06-09 11:54:26'
)
ORDER BY
    users_packages.has_fair DESC
LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0
```

Expected output

Store    ads will be shown first

VIP      ads will be shown second

Special  ads will be shown third

Comment: 'its a sql question database does not matter much' in this case true - but not in every case and backticks will throw errors in other sql dialects...

Comment: @P.Salmon  let me know if can help me out with any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort on multiple columns

```
order by users_packages.has_fair desc,users_packages.is_vip desc
```

If this does not produce what you want please add sample data and expected output as text to the question (or to  fiddle)

Comment: Expected output

Store    ads will be shown first

VIP      ads will be shown second

Special  ads will be shown third

Comment: how I can share sample data?